# Pull Data Validated List from Closed Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to pull a data-validated list using a named range in a closed workbook.

Both the source and active file sit on SharePoint. I don't have any connection problems between the workbooks, they otherwise link fine.

This code is not working whether the source workbook is closed or open.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub UpdateDataValidation()

    Dim ID_Range As String
      
    Dim sourcePath As String
    sourcePath = "sharepoint site url" 'change the path accordingly

    Dim sourceFileName As String
    sourceFileName = "workbook name" 'change the file name accordingly

    Dim sourceSheetName As String
    sourceSheetName = "Sheet1" 'change the sheet name accordingly

    Dim sourceReference As String
    sourceReference = "ID_Range" 'change the reference accordingly"

    Dim currentCell As Range
    Dim currentValue As String
    Dim validationList As String

    validationList = ""
    For Each currentCell In Worksheets(1).Range(sourceReference) 'any worksheet reference will do for our purposes here
        currentValue = ExecuteExcel4Macro("'" & sourcePath & "[" & sourceFileName & "]" & sourceSheetName & "'!" & currentCell.Address(, , xlR1C1))
        validationList = validationList & "," & currentValue
    Next currentCell

    validationList = Mid(validationList, 2)

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("K5:K504").Validation 'change the sheet name and range accordingly
        .Delete
        .Add _
            Type:=xlValidateList, _
            AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
            Formula1:=validationList
    End With

End Sub
```

My goal is to use the named range `ID_Range` vs. a hard-coded range so that the data validation list can grow/contract as needed. I am running an on-save code to trigger near-constant updates of this macro, and no issues there.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code is missing a couple of quotation marks. Try the code below:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub UpdateDataValidation()

    Dim ID_Range As String
      
    Dim sourcePath As String
    sourcePath = "sharepoint site url" 'change the path accordingly

    Dim sourceFileName As String
    sourceFileName = "workbook name" 'change the file name accordingly

    Dim sourceSheetName As String
    sourceSheetName = "Sheet1" 'change the sheet name accordingly

    Dim sourceReference As String
    sourceReference = "ID_Range" 'change the reference accordingly"

    Dim currentCell As Range
    Dim currentValue As String
    Dim validationList As String

    validationList = ""
    For Each currentCell In Worksheets(1).Range(sourceReference) 'any worksheet reference will do for our purposes here
        currentValue = ExecuteExcel4Macro("'" & sourcePath & "[" & sourceFileName & "]" & sourceSheetName & "'!" & currentCell.Address(, , xlR1C1))
        validationList = validationList & "," &
```